# Hibernate bidirectional relationship with owned collection of composite-elements

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'd like to create a very classic bidirectionnal parent-child relationship between two entities. The code:

```
public class History {
    public Long id;
    public List<HistoryField> fields;
}

public class HistoryField {
    public History history;
    public String foo, bar;
}
```

`HistoryField` is owned by its `History` parent.

To model this, I'm using the following hibernate mapping:

```
<class name="History" table="history">
    <id name="id" type="long" />
    <list name="fields" cascade="all" table="fields">
        <key column="history_id" />
        <list-index column="order_index" />
        <composite-element class="HistoryField">
            <property name="foo" />
            <property name="bar" />
        </composite-element>
    </list>
</class>
```

But **how do I specify** in the mapping the link between `HistoryField::history` back to the owning entity `History`?

The trick here is that the collection is owned, and defined as a composite-element (there is no ID for `HistoryField`, the primary key is the pair `history_id` + `order_index`). Classic examples of bidirectional parent-child relationships do not apply here; as they explain a relationship between two classes with IDs, whereas here the owned class does not have one.

Comment: @K.Nicholas Not really. The trick is that here it's an ID-less `HistoryField`, owned by `History` (in the database the primary key is the pair `history_id`+`order_index`). I thus need a `composite-element`.

Comment: I tried using a composite ID instead, but in that case how do you define `order_index` to be the indexing element of the owned list, managed by hibernate?

Comment: I presume the order_index is separate from the primary key. It doesn't need to be part of the primary key AFAIK. Show what you tried and ask about whatever problem you're having.

Comment: In my database model, the primary key of the `HistoryField` needs `history_id` + `order_index`, it's a many-to-one relationship. I do not want to change my database model to workaround an hibernate mapping issue

Comment: Yea, I get you. Good question. I haven't figured out how to do it in annotations yet. I'll remove my duplicate flag.

Comment: There is no Hibernate mapping issue. Components (Embeddables in the more modern JPA parlance) do not have IDs. The documentation notes that a component can specify a `<parent/>` element to get a back reference but is not clear whether this can be used with a collection of components i.e. in  `<composite-element/>` tag. Try that and see how it goes. See:  https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/components.html

Comment: Your question doesn't really clearly show the orderBy field in `HistoryField` issue so you could help to improve that.

Comment: I don't know about hibernate.xml mapping but I just created a composite key with two fields with annotations no problem.

Comment: @AlanHay Many thanks! Adding a `<parent>` annotation in my `<composite-element>` is indeed what is needed. Do you want to create an answer?

Comment: Ok. Have added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation notes that you can define a `<parent/>` element for a `<component/>` and while it does not explicitly mention this in the context of a collection of components specified by a `<composite-element/>` I would guess that it should work.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/components.html

> The `<component>` element allows a `<parent>` subelement that maps a
>   property of the component class as a reference back to the containing
>   entity.

Therefore:

```
<class name="History" table="history">
    <id name="id" type="long" />
    <list name="fields" cascade="all" table="fields">
        <key column="history_id" />
        <list-index column="order_index" />
        <composite-element class="HistoryField">
            <!-- name of the property refeencing the containing entity -->
            <parent name="history"/>
            <property name="foo" />
            <property name="bar" />
        </composite-element>
    </list>
</class>
```

When using annotations the `@Parent` annotation could be used similarly:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-Parent

> The Hibernate-specific `@Parent` annotation allows you to reference the
>   owner entity from within an embeddable.

```
@Embeddable
public class HistoryField {

    @Parent
    public History history;
    public String foo, bar;
}
```